# Bash For Loop with multiple input files of the same name

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am trying to combine a matched set of files with a For loop through a directory of files.

The files look like samename.csfasta and samename.qual, only the extensions are different.

The command to execute the program is:

```
solid2fastq samename.csfasta samename.qual -o samename
```

I have been looking for an example online but haven't found one.

if there were only one input:

```
for f in $FILES
do
     echo "Processing $f file....."
     solid2fastq $f -o $f

done
```

TIA

Comment: i don't understand. what does the input to the script look like?  what is $FILES?

Comment: So at the beginning of the script I direct it to the folder with the files. FILES=~/folder/folder/* I didn't include that sorry. Using the answer from pipi, I cd into the directory with the files in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files (`.cfasta` and `.qual`) are coupled then a code like the following

```
FILES=( *.csfasta )
for f in "${FILES[@]}"
do
  base=$(basename "$f" .csfasta)
  echo "Processing $f file....."
  solid2fastq "$f" "${base}.qual" -o "$base"
done
```

should be useful.